# Do all eggs give the same rewards when hatched?

Tags: pokemon-go

I hatched my first egg couple of hours ago and I got a udge surprise as a reward. That's what I got from my 5 km egg :

- A Porygon, 74 cp
- 17 candies
- 1000 xp
- over 9000 dust (joke I got around 1400...)

Are every eggs this much worth to hatch? Should I focus on hatching my eggs instead of running after some worthless Pidgeys?

Comment: Why not hatch the eggs while running after Pidgeys?

Comment: @Dragonrage Because if I was just hatching an egg, I would be running for real and focussing on travel as much distance as I can as fast as I can. When I'm trying to catch Pokémon, I'm stoping at every corner to make sure I'm still in the good direction. So, I'm walking slowly.

Comment: I just hatched two 10 km eggs: I got Onix and Electabuzz and ~2000 stardust, ~20 candies and 1500xp each.

Comment: You don't have to stop to catch a Poké. Once clicked on the map, the "battle" starts and you're in, catch it, regardless of how much you travel. I use this technique while sitting in the car.

Comment: Hard to run and throw Pokéball at the same time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of their contents, all eggs should be hatched if possible.

Unless I'm mistaken, the only way to remove an egg from your inventory is by hatching it. Since you have a limit of 9 eggs and eggs are essentially random, you'll eventually want to hatch all the eggs you can.

The questions then becomes "what order should I hatch them?"

I tend to hatch the longest walking length I can first, since the stronger Pokemon will help me out more in these earlier stages. But that's preference.

As for whether you should run around instead of catching Pokemon, that's a matter of balancing your resources.

If you have a ton of pokeballs, you'll likely want the candy and dust from catching Pokemon so you don't waste the resource. Or if you already have 9 eggs, you may want to rub and hatch a few so you have space for more.

Optimally you should never be sitting on excess eggs or pokeballs or potions etc, unless you have an excess of all of them. In which case, good job!

Comment: I use the shorter distance ones so I can get other pokemon eggs earlier.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here is a chart for egg hatching

Comment: Do you have a source for your image?