# Is there another way to get candies for rarer Pokemon not relying on catching more of them?

Tags: pokemon-go

Yesterday I caught a Dratini but as you guys know this will only give you 3 Dratini candy. So I was wondering, how am I supposed to evolve this Dratini when it is so diffucult to catch?

Answer (score 4):

Capturing (or hatching) Pokemon of an evolution-chain (like Dratini-Dragonair-Dragonite) will give you candy for that evolution-chain. That is the only way to get candies.

Rare and more powerful Pokemon appear as your character level goes up, so you will slowly begin to find more Dratini and eventually gather enough candies to evolve it.

Comment: According to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/273241/81131), you can also get candies from hatching eggs. I assume the candy type is dependent on the pokémon being hatched.

Comment: alright will take forever to evole this dratini haha well atleast I found another 1 today

Comment: @pushasha you're right. I added hatching to the answer. Although I'm not sure all pokemon can hatch from eggs, and it seems to be random whereas by catching you can try to track specific pokemon.

Comment: @kid great! I haven't found any dratini yet :)

Comment: @Chalkos Yeah, it's not a very reliable way to find candy for a specific pokémon, but worth mentioning nonetheless. Thanks for editing to include it :)

Answer (score 0):

There isnt really a way to speed it up but more often then not hatching a pokemon from an egg will give significantly more candy than catching it, if you are so lucky as to get a dratini from a 10km egg instead of say a Jinx, then you will be well on your way to getting your dragonair and then dragonite.